# R langugae : %in% promblem?

Tags: r

```
d1 <- data.frame("char"=c("a", "b", "c", "o", "m", "p"))
print("a" %in% d1)
```

I don't know why this code is "FALSE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That returns false because `d1` is a data frame - and a data frame is a `list` that contains columns. The `%in%` method as you've written it `"a" %in% d1` is testing if the value `"a"` is a column of `d1`, which it is not.

You can use `"a" %in% d1$char` to look in a specific column. You could use `"a" %in% unlist(d1)` to look in all the columns. You can use `"a" == d1` to compare `a` to every individual value in `d1`, and wrap that in `any()` as `any("a" == d1)` to also get a single `TRUE` result.

Things can get a little strange depending of if the data frame has multiple rows and if the vector you're testing has multiple values:

```
## 1 value in 1-row data frame works
"a" %in% data.frame(x = "a", y = "b")
# [1] TRUE

## With two values to test, we're still looking for individual columns
c("a", "b") %in% data.frame(x = c("a", "b"))
# [1] FALSE FALSE
## This is FALSE FALSE because there isn't a column that the whole
## column is "a", nor is there a column that the whole column is "b"

## Both "a" and "b" are whole columns here:
c("a", "b") %in% data.frame(x = "a", y = "b")
# [1] TRUE TRUE
## So we get TRUE TRUE

## Here's the way to test a whole column with more than 1 value:
list(c("a", "b")) %in% data.frame(x = c("a", "b"))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement inside your `print()` function is a logic test.

If you want to print the contents of your "char" column, you could try this:

```
d1 <- data.frame("char"=c("a", "b", "c", "o", "m", "p"))
print(d1$char)
```

Extra tips:

- You can change `"char"`to just `char` - the dataframe will still name your column `char`
- you don't need to use `print()`at all in this instance, just type `d1$char`